# String equalsIgnoreCase() vs JDK 7 Objects.equals(Object, Object)

Tags: java, string, object, equals

Do I lose anything by replacing the following:

```
    public final boolean testEquals(String left, String right) {
        if ((left == null && right != null) || (left != null && right == null)) {
            return false;
        } else if (left == null && right == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return left.equalsIgnoreCase(right);
        }
    }
```

With this from the JDK 7 [Objects class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html):

```
    public final boolean testEquals(String left, String right) {
        return Objects.equals(left,right);
    }
```

If I lose the case insensitivity, is replacing it with

```
Objects.equals(left.toLowerCase(),right.toLowerCase());
```

enough? Does it make sense to?

Comment: The newer way is definitely a lot clearer.

Comment: In your 1st case, that handle null case, but in the 3rd one, `left.toLowerCase()` or `right.toLowerCase()` may raise `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Kayaman It's clearer because `null` checks are missing. In the end it would be similar to the first approach.

Comment: @BackSlash You're right, I missed the equalsIgnoreCase.

Comment: @BachT and Kayaman  - Ah that makes sense, I totally forgot about null checks for possible NPE's after adding the toLowerCase(). There's no cleaner way to accomplish what I had hoped then, correct?

Comment: I think `testEquals` is equivalent to `return left == null ? right == null : left.equalsIgnoreCase(right)`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not only limited to JDK you can use

[`StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(CharSequence str1, CharSequence str2)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

from [apache-commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which is null-safe and will return

```
 StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(null, null)   = true
 StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(null, "abc")  = false
 StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("abc", null)  = false
 StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("abc", "abc") = true
 StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("abc", "ABC") = true
```

Comment: And if you don't have access to the apache-commons_lang library, you can replicate the Object.equals function which is
`left == right || (left != null && left.equalsIgnoreCase(right))`

Answer (score 1):

The method `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` is *"unfortunately"* a little more complex. You can look into the code, but it is well explained in [the javadoc itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

> Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations.
>   Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same
>   length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal
>   ignoring case.
>
> Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same ignoring case if at
>   least one of the following is true:
>
> - The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator)
> - Applying the method Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result
> - Applying the method Character.toLowerCase(char) to each character produces the same result